# Traceback that i can't fix

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making some code that is based on a game. I have gotten a traceback which I haven't encountered before even though I have used these lines of code before. Here is the code:

```
print ("please enter your Forename")
fore = input()
print ("Please enter your Surname")
sur = input
if fore == ("Benjamin"):
    print("ATTENTION. System Breach Detected. Purging System.")
```

and this is the error:

```
line 26, in <module>
    fore = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Benjamin' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, `input()` evaluates the user input as if it were a Python command. Thus, if you type "Benjamin", Python will try to evaluate `Benjamin` as a command. Consider using `raw_input()` instead.